# How to install .ipa on jailbroken iPhone over the AIR with out Apple certificate

Tags: ios

How can I install ipa/deb files on an iPhone device directly without user interference i.e. user should not use any terminal or third party tool like Cyberduck/iExplorer to install the file? The entire process should be automated. Exactly the same as Cydia does.

Comment: @Apurv Thanks for the reply but the question was how to install app OTA (over the Air) without having any of the Apple Certificate. What i believe that you have suggested to use the CyberDuck or other media to explorer the iPhone memory and drop the .app file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is jail broken, no provisional profile is required to install the application. You can directly install .ipa file into jail broken device.

If the device is not jail broken, you can install the .ipa file without provisional profile, if it is created with Enterprise Distribution certificate and in-House type provisional profile.

For rest of the distribution mode, you will require .ipa file and provisional profile having your device UDID linked to it.

Comment: is there any one how can help me out in this. I want to install the app OTA means from a web link only but with having any type of apple interference. Menas without having any certificate or ad hoc distribution account.

Comment: let me ask the question in different way, how to install a cracked ipa/ deb file on iPhone device directly. As in your answer this is mentioned that for Jail broken there is no need to have provisioning profile and all  but how to do that?

Comment: You can install it via iPhone Configuration utility. You can also install it via OTA. Upload the file at http://www.diawi.com/. Open the given link in mobile safari browser and install the app.

Comment: these all methods are not from the domain of jailbroken. These all required a valid provisioning profile and all. Where a jailbroken never need that. Like Cydia is there so any idea of this domain?